# PrototypeJS fails on chrome 83

Tags: google-chrome, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I have an old rails webapp that uses prototypeJS and scriptaculous. In Chrome 83, **sometimes**, the methodized functions don't get their definitions and nothing works, functions remain undefined. Couple of reloads again, it starts working.

For instance - $(...).build is not a function at this line.

`this.calendar_div = $(parent).build('div', {className: "calendar_date_select"}, style);`

And in the updateChanges of Ajax.Autocompleter of Scriptaculous

```
TypeError: element.getStyle is not a function
    at isDisplayed (javascripts/prototype.js?1591714063:3595:29)
    at klass._begin (javascripts/prototype.js?1591714063:3654:11)
    at klass.width (javascripts/prototype.js?1591714063:3801:39)
    at klass._compute (javascripts/prototype.js?1591714063:3724:57)
    at klass.get (javascripts/prototype.js?1591714063:3647:36)
    at klass.get (javascripts/prototype.js?1591714063:447:22)
    at Function.clonePosition (javascripts/prototype.js?1591714063:4319:29)
    at Object.clone (javascripts/prototype.js?1591714063:7459:20)
    at Object.options.onShow (javascripts/controls.js?1594789433:68:20)
    at klass.show (javascripts/controls.js?1594789433:95:71)
```

This is turning out to be a nightmare, since it blocks major important functions within the app. Any pointers/ideas on how I can immediately deal with this will be God-sent. Thank you for listening.

Comment: BTW, we use the latest prototypejs - 1.7.3 and scriptaculous 1.9.0

Comment: Firstly it sounds like it might be caching or if the web app is load balanced that one of the machines is out of date.   That being said I have a full web app that is still using the current version with Scripty and have no problems where the element prototype doesnt get extended.

Comment: Thanks Geek Num88. Actually it was a support webapp script that we added in the footer that caused this issue. What still suprises me however is that, this happens only in Chrome and not in any other browsers.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6827 - Is this connected to this somehow?